# How can we determine whether two metrics are uniformly equivalent or not given their Kaehler potential?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, complex-geometry

I have a question regarding how we can determine the uniform equivalence of two metrics (for the definition, see [here][1]). I'm wondering given two Kaehler metrics $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, if we have $\omega_1=i\partial\bar{\partial}f_1(z)$ and $\omega_2=i\partial\bar{\partial}f_2(z)$, is there a way to determine the conditions $f_1$ and $f_2$ need to satisfy for these two metrics to be uniformly equivalent? For example, if we only consider the metrics in a small neighbourhood in $\mathbb{C}^2$ around $0$, for $z\rightarrow 0$, if $f_2(z)=f_1(z)+O(z)$, it does not necessarily imply these two metrics are uniformly equivalent, instead, I think we need say $|\nabla^2 (f_1(z)-f_2(z))|= O(z)$?

I'd appreciate any comments or discussions, thanks in advance!

[1]: [https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Uniform_Equivalence/Metrics#:~:text=Let%20A%20be%20a%20set,%2Cd1](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Uniform_Equivalence/Metrics#:%7E:text=Let%20A%20be%20a%20set,%2Cd1))%2Dcontinuous.